# Security issues with S3 signed file link

Tags: amazon-s3

What is the security issue if I create a signed URL of the S3 file with an expiry time for client access?

Comment: any one can access this link with in the expire time.

Comment: apart from this is there any other issues?

Comment: Nothing else. These are the issues.